# @RequestScope annotation behaviour with Java inheritance

Tags: spring, spring-boot, inheritance, spring-annotations, requestscope

Lets say we have a class

```
@RequestScope 
public abstract class A {
    int a;
}
```

and another class which extends the above class

```
@Service 
public class B extends A {
    public int getA () { return a; }    
}
```

Is this class B's variable (that it is extending from A) is a request scoped variable?

**UPD**

I was going through the spring code, it says

> `/**
>   * Constant for the default scope name: {@code ""}, equivalent to singleton
>   * status unless overridden from a parent bean definition (if applicable).
>   */
>   public static final String SCOPE_DEFAULT = "";`

Also,

```
((AbstractBeanDefinition)((AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext) ctx).
getBeanDefinition("b")).scope
```

returns `"singleton"`

but if I mark class B with `@RequestScope` this property changes to `""`

 
which i assume is `sigleton` again

Answer (score 2):

To be inheritable annotation has to be marked with `@Inherited` annotation. Take a look at the source code of `@RequestScope`:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Scope(WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST)
public @interface RequestScope {

    /**
     * Alias for {@link Scope#proxyMode}.
     * <p>Defaults to {@link ScopedProxyMode#TARGET_CLASS}.
     */
    @AliasFor(annotation = Scope.class)
    ScopedProxyMode proxyMode() default ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS;

}
```

It's not marked with `@Inherited`. Therefore it doesn't affect subclasses. That means variable of class `B` from your example is not request scoped but singleton as it's supposed to be by default. You can find more details about predefined annotations [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html).

Comment: If we look at lombok getter annotation, It is also not marked with @Inherited annotation but seems to work.

Comment: @swayamraina because lombok getter annotation marks method, not a class. Subclass inherits the method with all annotations applied to it.

Comment: @swayamraina try to override method marked with lombok getter in subclass and you'll see